# statsmodels summary method result

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

There is a nice example of how *statsmodels* in *Python* can be used to fit regression equations: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html

However, I could not match how the confidence interval for each coefficient estimate is calculated e.g. for coefficient of GPA, the lower and upper bounds should be

```
0.4639 - 1.96 * 0.162 = 0.14638 and 0.4639 + 1.96 * 0.162 = 0.78142
```

But I see `0.132 & 0.796` respectively.

Is that only due to numerical accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confidence intervals for coefficient estimates are calculated using Student's t-distribution, not standard normal distribution which you used, hence the mismatch.

Comment: Is this not true? https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/5-2-cifrc.html

Comment: Usage of normal distribution is only justified in case of normal data and known variance (population variance, not sample variance). Let alone normality, if you don't know population variance (which you don't in the example you provided) - normal distribution loses its justification.

Comment: Usage of normal distribution is justified by large sample limits, that’s the main justification to using it for nonnormal or nonlinear models like logit, poisson and GLM

Comment: I don't see the point arguing about asymptotics when we're dealing with finite samples. Even if the distribution is known to be normal, if the population variance is unknown - sample mean will have Student's t-distribution, not normal distribution.

Comment: I think we are deviating from the main topic. My question is exactly what formula is used by `statsmodels` to construct the `confidence intervals`?

Comment: The formula is pretty much the same as the one you used except you need to use the 97.5th quantile of Student's t-distribution with 28 degrees of freedom (~2.048) instead of 97.5th quantile of standard normal distribution (1.96).